# I cannot set pyforms mode setting as terminal

Tags: python, pyforms

I use pyforms in Windows. From the [docs](https://pyforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started/run-terminal/#convert-the-application-to-run-in-the-terminal), I read that you can create a `settings.py` file in the same folder as your application to set my application's mode to `TERMINAL` by just adding `PYFORMS_MODE = 'TERMINAL'`. I assume without any additional effort you'd get your application opened in terminal mode. This doesn't work however, as my application still opens in `GUI` mode.

I noticed that in `__init__.py` inside the pyforms directory, the `conf` refers to the `settings.py` that is located inside that directory, which has this line

```
PYFORMS_MODE = os.environ.get('PYFORMS_MODE', 'GUI')
```

I tried to set the environment variable `PYFORMS_MODE` to `TERMINAL` inside my main application but it wouldn't persist without a bash trick as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17657905/7749262).

How am I supposed to set my application mode without changing pyform's code? I followed the docs step by step so I don't think I miss anything during installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import pysettings in your application and reference the settings file from there:

```
from pysettings import conf
import settings
conf += settings
```

See [the accompany tutorial](https://github.com/UmSenhorQualquer/pyforms/blob/master/tutorials/3.CodeOrganization/PersonWindow.py).