# How to export environment variable permanently using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, environment-variables

I am newbie in Ruby and want to export environment variable permanently to host system.

Right now I have following ruby script on which I am  working. In this script there is ENV command that adds URL env var to current execution env and it works fine. But I want to make this change persistent to hostmachine, in my case its linux.
how can I do that?

```
require 'singleton'

java_import com.test.TestClass;
class RubyClient
  include Singleton

 def initialize
  ENV['URL'] = 'http://localhost'
 end
end

def test_client
  puts TestClass.getEnv
end

class TestClass{
 public String getEnv({
  return StringUtils.trimToNull(System.getenv("URL"));
 }
}
```

Comment: You don't; this would be a huge potential security risk. Best you could do is modify a shell startup config (if the appropriate file is writable by your script). The larger question is why you'd want to do this--it seems like an XY problem.

Comment: I agree with @DaveNewton. You probably want to pass your URL as an argument to some class initializer or method, or make it a module-level constant. Environment variables are more often used as overrides; they are not the right way to pass data around inside a Ruby application.

Comment: @DaveNewton, Todd, Somehow I am also agree on this. I added few more lines of code in here. So full scenario is, this ruby will export var and this var will be used by JRuby java class. Now ruby export its in current shell and its not visible to java class. I cann't pass URL to class directly. its my limitation.

Comment: It just doesn't work like that; you could run the Java code that expects the environment variable in a sub-process (which seems cumbersome), or start up the JRuby code with a more-flexible configuration mechanism.

Comment: As I mentioned, don't use the ENV array to set values. Set them as instance variables or constants that can be *overridden* by ENV variables and pass them to your Java methods, or have them get read from a configuration file. If using RSpec, you can also set the values with #let statements in your tests.

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible. Environment variables apply to the currently running process, and *only* to the currently process. Child processes started by this process will initially inherit their parent's environment, but can (and often do) override it with its own.

One process *cannot* change another process's environment. This has nothing to do with Ruby or Java, this is a fundamental security property of all Unices as well as many other OSs that have a comparable concept of "environment".

Answer (score 0):

### Use Direnv or Dotenv

This is not how environment variables work. You export them in the current shell, and they are *inherited* by subshells. You can't really export variables from subshells back to a parent shell.

There are tools that make it seem like you can do this (e.g. direnv) but if you want a value to be read into a parent shell you need to ensure that the shell is reading in a stored value from disk before each command. Direnv or dotenv hooked into your shell will accomplish this from a pragmatic perspective, but the parent shell itself never truly inherits from a subshell.

Comment: when you say subshells inherits env variables. So in my case Jruby is trigger by ruby only. So ideally Jruby process is nothing but ruby sub-process and its should see the variable set in ruby env on the fly not on startup.  Or can we think when ruby trigger Jruby execution that we can add some hook in its life.

Comment: I don't think Dotenv really has a place in the toolchain in 2021, and its better to use Direnv (or any other language agnostic option) or encrypted secrets (yes its available as a gem outside of Rails) or to do the configuration for example in the docker container.

Answer (score -2):

You shouldn't set environment variable like that, you can read ot only, it is kinda configuration.
You can take help from the gem dotenv.