# set environment variable in python that can be accessed by other programs

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, environment-variables

I have gone through so many SO solutions but couldn't find exact solution for this, actually i have a python file file.py in which im defining a environment variable. I want to use this environment variable from my bash script script.py

file.py

```
import os
os.environ['user'] = 'Jack'
```

script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

echo  "Running Python to get environment Variables"
# file_path='./env'
python3 ./file.py
echo $user
```

I want to know how can we change environment variables from python that can be used in other process within bash. Also i would like to add that i had tried this kind of approach, im not sure if this can be a better practise

file2.py

```
def get_username():
  key = 'user'
  value = 'Jack'
  return f'export {key}={value}'
```

My bash script would look like this

```
#!/bin/bash
echo  "Running Python to get environment Variables"
command=`python3 -c 'import file2;print(file2.get_username())'`
$command
echo $user
```

Comment: `script.py` is definitely not a Python script.

Comment: @matszwecja my bad it should be script.sh

Comment: You need to set the env variables in the OS if you are using a secondary script to grab it, please check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17657905/8382028

Comment: Python cannot change its parent's environment any more than Bash can. The usual solution if you need it is to have Python print something that the caller can interpret, like `eval "$(python -c 'print export FOO="bar"')"` or `user=$(python -c 'print "jack"')`

Comment: @tripleee thanks for this solution, i tried this kind of approach it worked for me. Is there any other way we can make this work from python ?

Comment: As in "without cooperation of the calling process"? No, by definition. Again, see the duplicate.